# Iterate through all undeleted Documents in a Lucene (.Net) index

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I want to get the count of all un-deleted documents of a Lucene (.Net 2.4) index and then read my stored fields of all or a range of these docs. 
After reading the Lucene help I'm not quite sure, whether IndexReader.NumDocs() returns the count of all docs or only the undeleted ones. Can I simply iterate through IndexReader.Document[] and or does it contain deleted Documents?

If NumDocs() and Docmuent[] *does* contain both deleted und undeleted docs I suppose I'll have to do something like this:

```
int totalCount = reader.NumDocs();
int totalCountUndeleted = totalCount;
for (int iDoc = 0; iDoc < totalCount; iDoc++)
  if (reader.IsDeleted(iDoc))
    totalCountUndeleted--;

for (int iDoc = 0; iDoc < totalCount; iDoc++)
{
  if (!reader.IsDeleted(iDoc))
  {
     Document doc = reader.Document(iDoc);
     // read fields
  }
}
```

Is this the right way or is there any other possible way? Thanks

Comment: I found reader.NumDeletedDocs(). So getting totalCount is easier: int totalCount = reader.NumDocs() - reader.NumDeletedDocs();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way. Until you optimize your index, the documents will not be removed.

Alternatively, if you have a query like `*:*` which matches all document, you can run that instead. The query method will probably be somewhat slower, but maybe more standard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried a normal search with ":" (colon) as query (Query indexQuery = parser.Parse(":"); ), but it didn't work for me. (ParseException Cannot parse ':': Encountered "":" ": "" at line 1, column 0.
Was expecting one of:
    <OR> ...
    <NOT> ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    ":" ...
    "^" ...
    <QUOTED> ...
    <FUZZY_SLOP> ...
    <PREFIXTERM> ...
    <WILDTERM> ...
    "[" ...
    "{" ...

Comment: The Lucene docu states you can use a colon to specify the field to search in ("FIELDNAME:searchstring")

Comment: @gumo: sorry, SO considers `*` a keyword. Can you true `*:*`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. The search with <star colon star> (how to do the formatting in comments?) works for me, thanks. I think that's the best way for me.

Comment: FYI: I compared both ways and the search with `*:*` was around 5 times faster than the iterating. (And to answer my own question: The formatting in comments can be done with "`")

Comment: @gumo: cool, thanks for the info. I wouldn't have expected the query to be any faster, much less 5 times faster. Good to know!

Answer (score 1):

`IndexReader.NumDocs` will give you number of active documents. `IndexReader.MaxDoc` is the number one greater than maximum document number in the index. Following code will read all the active documents in the index.

```
int max = reader.MaxDoc();
for (int iDoc = 0; iDoc < max; iDoc++)
{
  if (!reader.IsDeleted(iDoc))
  {
     Document doc = reader.Document(iDoc);
     // read fields
  }
}
```